# Booting a Linux system backed up with rsync

Tags: linux, boot, grub, rsync

I've managed to back up my system with `rsync` as described on this [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync).

What I don't understand is the part about booting from the partition containing the backed up system. AFAIU, Linux Mint uses GRUB, but I practically no nothing about that other than the fact that it has something to with managing booting. Could someone explain in detail what I would have to do here? Still a Linux n00b, sorry ;-)

Comment: That backup method does not result in a bootable copy of your system.

Comment: Well... thanks ;-) Would you mind pointing me to a resource that explains how one would do that or that features "better ways" of backing up and restoring Linux systems?

Comment: Try [REAR](http://relax-and-recover.org/).